# Trying to reverse engineer a Bioweight USB scale 8 byte payload

Tags: hash, usb, reverse-engineering, checksum

I am trying to reverse engineer a Bioweight USB scale. A am able to send commands and get return values through the USB port, but communication packets seem to be appended with a 2 byte hash or checksum or some type of control.

Here are some sample packets. I know the meaning of the first 6 bytes but the last 2 bytes are what I suppose are just checking.

[image]

Can anyone spot what kind of checking algorithm is being used?

Comment: A single byte is displayed as two hexadecimal digits.  Did you mean to say that you know the meaning of the first 6 bytes but don't understand the last two?

Comment: Yes, correct will change te question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a CRC-16 of bytes 1 through 5 (i.e. all the bytes of the message except the first one which is 0xFF all the time).

I verified this by entering the bytes "0x03 0x01 0x55 0xAA 0x55" into an [online CRC-16 calculator](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html).

By the way, every USB data packet has a CRC-16 appended to it already.  I am not sure how you obtained this data; maybe you are just seeing the CRC-16 that is built into the USB specification.